# Get batterylevel of more than one bluetoothdevices (beacons)

Tags: android, service, beacon, batterylevel

I want to get the battery level of more than one bluetooth device in android using the gatt service.
My current code is this (I am sorry that it looks a bit chaotic):

```
public void readCustomCharacteristic() {
// Initializes Bluetooth adapter.
final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
        (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner().startScan(new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            super.onScanResult(callbackType, result);
            //Log.i("Beacons", "callbacktype: " + String.valueOf(callbackType));
            Log.i("Beacons", "result: " + result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();
            Log.i("Beacons", "Devicescan: " + (btDevice != null));

                BluetoothGatt bluetoothGatt = btDevice.connectGatt(
                        getApplicationContext(), false, new BluetoothGattCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
                                //super.onConnectionStateChange(gatt, status, newState);
                                Log.i("Beacons", "areServicesDiscovered: " + gatt.discoverServices());
                                if(gatt.discoverServices()) {
                                    onServicesDiscovered(gatt, status);
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
                                if (gatt.discoverServices()) {
                                    //if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {

                                            Log.d("Beacons", "Number of Services: " + gatt.getServices().size());

                                            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void run() {

                                                    BluetoothGattCharacteristic chars = gatt.getServices().get(0).getCharacteristic(Battery_Level_UUID);
                                                    Log.i("Beacons", "charsstringval: " + chars.getValue().length);

                                                }
                                            });


                                }
                            }
                        });
        }
    });
}
```

I have to scan more than one beacon, and when it is scanning a device and it only getssometimes a service.
The problem is when the code wants to read the characteristic the service handle is again null. I'm desperate and I hope you can help me.

Comment: Please edit: Add a clear description of your problem and your solution approach, then the code (if you cannot make it shorter, then like it is) and what you tried and how it did (not) work.

Comment: I tried to cleanup the question a bit. Please re-edit if you did mean something else. And have a look at the code formatting. The single ``}`` in the end looked like it was too much, but maybe the indention of the rest of rest of the code was the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In short, because your runnable runs on a different thread, the value of `gatt.getServices()` may have changed.

I would simply retrieve the updated services list, check the size, and then only make the call if there is at least one service.

```
if (gatt.getServices().size() > 0) {
    BluetoothGattCharacteristic chars = gatt.getServices().get(0).getCharacteristic(Battery_Level_UUID);
    Log.i("Beacons", "charsstringval: " + chars.getValue().length);
}
```